# Catch value(s) with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet below, but I don't know how to catch value(s) with `jQuery`. How could we get some values from input text?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileInput2").uploadify({
        //How get value from input (fileInput2)
    });
});
</script>
<div class="demo">
    <input id="fileInput2" name="fileInput2" type="file" />
    <a href="javascript:$('#fileInput2').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try:-
$("#fileInput2").uploadify({
        alert($("#fileInput2").val());
    });

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#fileInput2").uploadify(
        {
            // Get value
            var input_field_value = $(this).val()
       });
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">
    <input id="fileInput2" name="fileInput2" type="file" /> 
    <a href="javascript:$('#fileInput2').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You are calling the `uploadify` function on `fileInput2`, so if you write `$(this)`, it will refer to this same element, which is `fileInput2` textbox. So writing `$(this).val()` will give you the value of this input element.

Comment: Thanks, but allways get empty values

Comment: Maybe problam is type: file?
When i use type text, everything works.

Comment: @gloris: no the problem isn't there, because it works perfectly for me as type: file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `val()` method:

```
$("#fileInput2").val();
```

Or:

```
$("#fileInput2").uploadify({
  alert($(this).val());
});
```